# Windows Number Of files

Tags: windows, cmd

On windows server 2012, I can see the number of files with the following command but I need to print this file number in []. I have not reached a conclusion in my research on how it is done, can you help?

```
dir / b / s / a-d | find / v / c "::"
```

The output of this command is: 213123,

I [33432] (must be in square brackets) I want to write this.

Windows version: Windows Server 2012

How can I resolve it?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `FOR /F` statement in a .bat script to generate the count and print it out.

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('DIR /B /S /A:-D ^| FIND /V /C "::"') DO (ECHO [%%a])
```

If this is done at the command line (not in a .bat script), then do not double the percent character.

```
FOR /F %a IN ('DIR /B /S /A:-D ^| FIND /V /C "::"') DO (ECHO [%a])
```

If you wanted to push ahead into PowerShell, you could use:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object { '[' + $_.Count + ']' }
```

Or, with all the cryptic aliases that should never be written into a script:

```
gci -File|measure|%{'['+$_.Count+']'}
```